# cannot use import statement outside a module - Excel custom functions add-in: proper way to use JS functions defined in taskpane.js in functions.js

Tags: javascript, office-addins

Newbie here in Office add-ins and JavaScript, so please be patient!

I created a Javascript Excel custom functions add-in, by using the Yeoman generator. In one of my custom function I want to use a JS function defined in an external file. So I defined a function named testExternal and placed it in taskpane.js file:

```
export function testExternal() {
  return 1;
}
```

then in the functions.js file I have:

```
import { testExternal } from "../taskpane/taskpane.js";
```

and in my custom function:

```
console.log(testExternal());
```

When debugging, I'm getting the desired 1 in console, but also get the "Cannot use import statement outside a module" error message:

[image]

This happens not only in debug mode, but also when the add-in is published on a web server and the add-in is sideloaded. So the external defined function is working correctly, but:

1. is there any way to get rid of that error message?
2. what are the steps to use a function defined in another JS file (not in taskpane.js)? Let's say I want to have all my utils functions in a file named utils.js and use that in my custom functions. What is the best location for utils.js and how can be automatically added to the dist folder, when the project is build in VS Code?

Thank you for your time,

Adrian

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`javascript` + `html` :

If you are using native `javascript` "for browser" (I'm mean it's not a node application that use packages, etc...).
When you import a script where you need to use `import` statement you need to set his `type` as `module` :

```
<script src="app.js" type="module"></script>

utils.js
function foo() {
    return 'Hello';
}

export { foo };
```

This one is a `module` :

```
app.js
import { foo } from 'utils.js';
```

`node.js` :

If you want want to use `ES Modules` you have to set the property `type` of your `package.json` as `module` :

```
package.json
{
    "type": "module"
}
```

If `office add-in` doesn't allow you to use `ES Modules` you have to use `Nodes modules` to import / export things :

```
utils.js
function foo() {
    return "Hello";
}

module.exports = foo;
// or
module.exports.foo = foo
```

Then :

```
const foo = require('utils');
// or
const { foo } = require('utils');
```

Comment: Office add-in uses node.js, it should works exepted if it's not compoatible with ES Modules, so they have to use nodes modules. I'll edit

Comment: After some research : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/develop-overview. Building office add-in with javasript is possible eather by  using `script` but also by ising `node.js` ;)

Comment: After adding `module.exports = testExternal;` to taskpane.js and `const testExternal = require("../taskpane/taskpane.js");` to functions.js, I'm getting these errors in console:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`
`Uncaught Error: ES Modules may not assign module.exports or exports.*, Use ESM export syntax, instead: ./src/taskpane/taskpane.js` and this Intellisense warning over "require": `File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES module.`

Comment: Are you using `node.js` or do you import your js with `script` balises ?

Comment: I have this in my taskpane.html: `<script src="../functions/functions.js"></script>`. I'm using node.js when debugging on my computer (with localhost), but the error is the same when the files are deployed on a web server.

Comment: Ok perfect, look at my answer I edited to add the answer when you are using `script` balises .Actually you just have to add `type="module"` ;)

Comment: Great, no probleme ;)